# Определить, какую Activity запускать

Tags: android, android-intent

Моя задача.
В мини-игре есть несколько уровней. Переходы между уровнями сделать несложно.
Каждый уровень - это Activity. С фрагментами пока не удалось.
Теперь хочу вставить между уровнями Таблицу рекордов. Это тоже новая Activity.
С помощью Intent передаю результат игрока в мою Таблицу рекордов.
А теперь вопрос:

Мне нужно научится узнавать какая из Activity вызывает Таблицу рекордов.

Чтобы правильно разместить рекорд. И чтобы знать какую Activity потом запустить (следующий уровень)

Comment: вам нужно использовать файл или базу данных - из нее и читать/писать напрямую где требуется, там же делать отметки к чему относится информация. эта ваша идея передавать через интенты практически нежизнеспособна.

Comment: Передавайте вместе с рекордом запись об активности. Для хранения данных между сессиями используйте БД или `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению базой данных пока не владею. 
И передавать нужно всего-то один параметр.
Может мне стоит запускать Таблицу рекордов иначе. Как дополнительное окно. И потом возвращаться к уровню который запустил её. А там уже победа уровня и переход на следующий.

Comment: @pavlofff, а если в putExtra(param, value) записывать отметку , а в другой активити ее считывать?

Comment: SharedPreferences это хорошая идея. Постараюсь узнать об этом сейчас.

Comment: в `SharedPreferences` пишите, подумайте хотя бы о том, что игра ваша наверное не одноразовая, а при выходе из нее все информация, переданная через интенты будет утрачена (соответственнои рекорды) , это наиболее очевидный практический недостаток, не говоря о крайне непригодной архитектуре вашего решения.

Comment: можно использовать [эту простую библиотеку](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper) для хранения информации, она намного удобнее преференсов и данные любых типов позволяет хранить

Comment: Вообще, если вы планируете серьезно кодить, разобраться в БД самое время - пока мало данных и их несложно вносить/читать, при необходимости сортировать. Грамотные уроки есть на том же startandroid

Comment: Спасибо за библиотеку и за советы. Как раз и собираюсь учить БД. Но для её использования нужно чтобы эта база работала когда отправлю приложение в Play Market. Где эти данные хранить?

Comment: они будут хранится на устройстве, на которое будет установлено ваше приложение. Если вы хотите хранить онлайн, то вам понадобится сервер или что то вроде Firebase (но на бесплатном аккаунте там большие ограничения)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно передавать информацию с помощью метода `putExtra(param, value)` и получать в вызываемой активности с помощью `getExtras()`. Таким образом можно передавать несколько значений, используя разные ключи, примерно так:

```
intent.putExtra(RECORD, moves);
intent.putExtra(CALLING_ACTIVITY, activity_id);
```

Или можно все засунуть в один бундель:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt(RECORD, moves);
extras.putInt(CALLING_ACTIVITY, activity_id);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

И получить:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int record = extras.getInt(RECORD);
int calling_activity = extras.getInt(CALLING_ACTIVITY);
```

Вместо `putInt` и `getInt` можно использовать `putString` и `getString`.

Comment: Спасибо. Я таким способом передаю информацию об рекорде игрока, из уровня в Таблицу рекордов.
Вопрос в том, что Таблицу будет вызывать по очереди каждый уровень.

Comment: Вот так я передаю рекорд:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BrainSecondLevel.class);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY, moves);
            startActivity(intent);
А так получаю:
Intent Intent = getIntent();
        moves = Intent.getIntExtra("INTENT_KEY", -1);

Comment: Если такой код вставить после каждого уровня, то как определить какая из Activity вызвала таблицу. Чтобы потом знать какой следующий уровень запустить?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Для каждой активити своя метка, когда вызывает таблицу считаете метку и в зависимости от ее значения строите нужную вам логику

Comment: Похоже что Bundel как раз то, что мне нужно.  
Большое спасибо! Пойду пробовать.